# Xcode 9.2 crashing while trying to access keychain

Tags: xcode, keychain, macos-high-sierra, xcode9.3

My xcode version 9.2 is crashing on start, crashlog suggested that its crashing while trying to access keychain. The keychain has some issue because every application which trying to access keychain is crashing. If i open individual file of project, xcode opens the file and when i go to xcode preference -> Account it crashed again so it seems to me i had added my apple account in xcode and crashing when trying to access that account. How can i fix this, how can i remove that account from xcode from terminal or some where in finder as i am unable to run xcode.

Please see crash logs.

```
       Process:               Xcode [30293]
       Path:                  
       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
       Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
       Version:               9.3 (14154)
       Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-14154000000000000~2
       Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
       Parent Process:        ??? [1]
       Responsible:           Xcode [30293]
       User ID:               536863420

       Date/Time:             2018-11-23 15:18:05.525 +0000
       OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.13.6 (17G3025)
       Report Version:        12
       Bridge OS Version:     <device not connected>
       Anonymous UUID:        4C96C023-6837-7F83-1532-C3005D92C816


       Time Awake Since Boot: 18000 seconds

       System Integrity Protection: enabled

       Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

       Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
       Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
       Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

       Application Specific Information:
       ProductBuildVersion: 9E145
       ASSERTION FAILURE in 
     /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTFrameworks/DVTFrameworks- 
     14133/DVTFoundation/Portal/DVTKeychainService.m:64
     Details:  A method claimed to have failed but provided no error!
    Object:   <DVTKeychainService: 0x7f9a6f6f8e10>
    Method:   -fetchPasswordForUsername:service:keychain:error:
    Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7f9a6a508510>{number = 1, name = main}
    Hints:   
    0: Replacement view is installing: <IDEAccountPrefsPaneController: 
    0x7f9a6f97a0f0 representing: <DVTExtension 0x7f9a6bea43a0: 
    AccountsPrefs (Xcode.PreferencePane.Accounts) v0.1 from 
   com.apple.dt.IDEKit>>
   Backtrace:
   0   -[IDEAssertionHandler
```

handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1   _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2   _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3   -[DVTKeychainService 
      fetchPasswordForUsername:service:keychain:error:] (in DVTFoundation)
  4   +[DVTDeveloperAccountCredentials _keychainServiceAccountCredentialsForUsername:keychain:error:] (in DVTFoundation)

Comment: It sounds like the main problem is with your keychain, not Xcode, so this may not be a programming question.  You may want to ask at apple.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks, yes actually the issue is in keychain itself which going to take time to fix so i was wondering is somehow i can fix this xcode issue atleast i would be able to run it till the time keychian issue fixes.